# Is there a way to use the cfg(feature) check on multiple statements?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to minimize the following feature check?

```
#[cfg(feature = "eugene")]
pub mod eugene_set_steam_id;
#[cfg(feature = "eugene")]
pub mod eugene_balance;
#[cfg(feature = "eugene")]
pub mod eugene_force_map;
#[cfg(feature = "eugene")]
pub mod eugene_rating;
#[cfg(feature = "eugene")]
pub mod eugene_stat;
#[cfg(feature = "eugene")]
pub mod eugene_steam_id;
#[cfg(feature = "eugene")]
pub mod eugene_top;
```

To something like:

```
#[cfg(feature = "eugene")] {
    pub mod eugene_set_steam_id;
    pub mod eugene_balance;
    pub mod eugene_force_map;
    pub mod eugene_rating;
    pub mod eugene_stat;
    pub mod eugene_steam_id;
    pub mod eugene_top;
}
```

This would better convey meaning and be more ergonomic.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [cfg-if crate](https://crates.io/crates/cfg-if) provides the `cfg-if!` macro that should do what you want:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate cfg_if;

cfg_if! {
    if #[cfg(feature = "eugene")] {
        pub mod eugene_set_steam_id;
        pub mod eugene_balance;
        pub mod eugene_force_map;
        pub mod eugene_rating;
        pub mod eugene_stat;
        pub mod eugene_steam_id;
        pub mod eugene_top;
    } else {
    }
}
```

In fact, it even describes itself using your words:

> A macro to ergonomically define an item depending on a large number of `#[cfg]` parameters. Structured like an if-else chain, the first matching branch is the item that gets emitted.

Comment: One question - why is this `else` block necessary?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy because the macro is defined to expect it. I don't know if it could be changed or not.

Comment: @VP. The `else` block is no longer necessary

Answer (score 24):

You could create a private module that import all the files, and then let the parent module re-export everything from that private module:

```
#[cfg(feature = "eugene")]
#[path = ""]
mod reexport_eugene_modules {
    pub mod eugene_set_steam_id;
    pub mod eugene_balance;
    pub mod eugene_force_map;
    pub mod eugene_rating;
    pub mod eugene_stat;
    pub mod eugene_steam_id;
    pub mod eugene_top;
}

#[cfg(feature = "eugene")]
pub use reexport_eugene_modules::*;
```

You still need to write that `#[cfg]` line twice though.

Comment: Actually I have decided to use your approach because it does not need a dependency and it can be done simply using the language itself.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work for external crate imports.

Comment: What does `#[path = ""]` do?