# How to group imports in Rust with conditional compilation?

Tags: import, rust, package

I am looking to group all my imports with conditional compilation.

I know that the `#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]` attribute organises the import, but it only works for one import.

How can I import multiple packages with one conditional compilation attribute?

I am looking for something like:

```rust
#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
{
    use windows_lib1;
    use windows_lib2;
}

#[cfg(target_os = "linux")]
{
    use linux_lib1;
    use linux_lib2;
}
```

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Is there a way to use the cfg(feature) check on multiple statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43070430/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster none of the answer gives the simple solution that applies to use imports.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can group use imports this way:

```
#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
use {
    windows_lib1,
    windows_lib2,
};
```

Comment: "never found it documented but it's what my experience tends to prove" → It's actually [well documented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html) that attributes apply to the following "thing" (and outer attributes (`#!`) to the "thing" that contains them).

Comment: @mcarton Can we really take "thing" as a spec word ? What is it ? A paragraph ? A function ? A module ?This is way too fuzy and that's why I maintain it's not documented.

Comment: Are you complaining about vocabulary when you are not using proper vocabulary either? `use` is not a statement, it's an item. They use "thing" in the documentation because those terms have precise definitions that are usually not important for most people. Attributes apply to most things, be they items, statements, function parameters, etc, so the documentation just call them "thing".

Comment: In such formal documentation I would expect precision. Thing is not a well defined term imo too.

Comment: The documentation explains in detail to what things attributes can be applied, so "thing" is well defined in this context: "Thing" refers to an item declaration, external block, function, implementation, module, statement, expression, enum variant, struct/union field, match expression arm or generic type or lifetime parameter.